# Preserving accented letters in small caps in French in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, localization

I have a Word document where the section titles are in small caps. This document is in French. Accents in the small caps text disappear, e.g. “Caractères accentués” comes out as CARACTERES ACCENTUES. Strangely, ç is correctly capitalized to “Ç”.

I'm using Word 2010 in English, if it matters.

How can I prevent Word from stripping the accents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that we French have the privilege of having our very own option in Word:

In Word 2010, go to File > Options > Proofing ("Vérification"), and check **Enforce accented uppercase in French** ("Majuscules accentuées").

Comment: ET VOILA!!!! :)

Answer (score 7):

I thought this odd behavior had to be specific to French. Surely letters such as `å` or `ö` would be correctly capitalized to `ÅÖ`, and indeed they are. Furthermore, if I change the language of the text to, say, German, then all accents are preserved. In fact, the behavior is specific to text in the “French (France)” language — accented letters in other French variants such as “French (Belgium)” are not mangled in small caps.

So I switched my document's language to “French (Monaco)”, and accented letters in small caps are now rendered correctly.

Comment: bravo :) bien fait !