# Word 2013 - Proofing - Enforce accented uppercase in French

Tags: microsoft-word, language, microsoft-word-2013, proofing

In my company I have been asked to conduct an internal training in MS Word 2013 to some participants!  As I am going thru various options in MS Word 2013, I came across this option ‘Enforce accented uppercase in French’ under Proofing.

I can easily skip this stating that I and also the participants do not know French, but if possible I would like to cite an example.

May I know what it means and how it works? Can someone share some examples of French words or a sentence where this would be applicable and how it results with and without this option checked?

The default language set in Windows 7 is English. Let me know if that needs to be changed to French for this option to work. I have no knowledge of French language as such.

I took some inputs from this post [Preserving accented letters in small caps in French in Word](https://superuser.com/questions/589760/preserving-accented-letters-in-small-caps-in-french-in-word)  but nothing changed in my document when tried with the words mentioned therein.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Enforce accented uppercase in French**
(in word options, proofing)

Alert you to French words that contain uppercase letters that are missing an accent mark. When you are using the French Language in `Microsoft-Word`, by default this option is always turned on, because the dictionary for this language includes the accented uppercase form of words in this language.

**Example**
`MAJUSCULES ACCENTUÉES` (when the option is on)
`MAJUSCULES ACCENTUEES` (when the option is off)

In order to use it (show red lines if no accents appear when needed in French word), you have to change the Language of the document in `Word` to `French France` for example, you can do it by clicking on the Status Bar, English(the country) Language, in that case the French Dictionary will be activated to check spelling.
You can change the Language in `Microsoft Word` for the document needed only without changing in `Windows`
The below picture is a `Word Document` showing an example of accented words
Usually lower case is always accented but Upper case need this option.
Like you said in `English` it is not needed.

[image]